# Plot a graphs from a JSON structure which contains timestamps of different location

Tags: javascript, json, timestamp

i have to plot a graph in javascript and all i have is a JSON with locations and timestamp , it is like an array and i have to plot the time spent at all the locations using a graph.

Comment: bam :) `chrome://tracing` also there is this https://github.com/hrydgard/minitrace

Answer (score 0):

you can use nvd3 to create graphs in javascript
http://nvd3.org/

here is an example code for a graph given an array http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html

if you are using angular js then you can try angular nvd3 http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/